# Implementing TypeAdapterFactory with TypeAdapter in Kotlin

Tags: android, gson, kotlin

I'm trying implement some particular GSON TypeAdapter in Kotlin language for my android project.

The issue I'm facing is compile error with inability to infer type: `Type inference failed: 'T' cannot capture 'in (T..T?'. Type parameter has an upper bound 'Enum<T>' that cannot be satisfied capturing 'in' projection`

The code is following:

```
  class SmartEnumTypeAdapterFactory(fallbackKey: String) : TypeAdapterFactory {

     private val fallbackKey = fallbackKey.toLowerCase(Locale.US)

     override fun <T : Any> create(gson: Gson?, type: TypeToken<T>): TypeAdapter<T>? {
        val rawType = type.rawType
        return if (!rawType.isEnum) null else SmartEnumTypeAdapter(rawType)
     }

     class SmartEnumTypeAdapter<T : Enum<T>>(classOfT: Class<T>) : TypeAdapter<T>() {

        override fun write(out: JsonWriter?, value: T) {
           TODO("not implemented")
        }

        override fun read(`in`: JsonReader?): T {
           TODO("not implemented")
        }
     }
  }
```

The reason I want to have `classOfT: Class<T>` as parameter for TypeAdapter is out of context of this problem.

Comment: This is a really tricky case... Have you tried implementing this thing in Java? Because then you could convert to Kotlin and see if that works, but so far I've not gotten this to work in either language.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible because the method you are overwriting (`TypeFactory.create`) has no upper bound (which translates to `<T : Any>` in Kotlin). In your `create` method, `T` is not 
guaranteed to be a `Enum<T>` (so, it's not possible to pass it as argument to your adapter).

What you can do is simply remove the upper bound in your adapter class and keep it private to make sure only your factory can create instances of it (and the factory already validates if the type is an enum).

```
class SmartEnumTypeAdapterFactory(fallbackKey: String) : TypeAdapterFactory {

    private val fallbackKey = fallbackKey.toLowerCase(Locale.US)

    override fun <T> create(gson: Gson?, type: TypeToken<T>): TypeAdapter<T>? {
        val rawType = type.rawType
        return if (!rawType.isEnum) null else SmartEnumTypeAdapter(rawType)
    }

    private class SmartEnumTypeAdapter<T>(classOfT: Class<in T>) : TypeAdapter<T>() {

        override fun write(out: JsonWriter?, value: T) {
            TODO("not implemented")
        }

        override fun read(`in`: JsonReader?): T {
            TODO("not implemented")
        }
    }
}
```

(`classOfT` is a `Class<in T>` because `TypeToken.rawType()` returns a `Class<? super T>`)